# how to start Apache tomcat on system start up?

Tags: windows, tomcat

Previously our system was on Ubuntu based server where we have managed to automatically start up the Apache tomcat server on system start up , currently we moved to windows platform , i want to do the same on windows , i want my Apache tomcat server to start on system start up ?

Comment: which version of tomcat you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Install apache tomcat as windows service, and change its `startup type` as `automatic`

use following link for more info
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services